# Error while clicking linkbutton in MasterPage

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am getting following error.
Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that  configuration specifies the same validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that  configuration specifies the same validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster.

Source Error:

The source code that generated this unhandled exception can only be shown when compiled in debug mode. To enable this, please follow one of the below steps, then request the URL:

1. Add a "Debug=true" directive at the top of the file that generated the error. Example:

or:

2) Add the following section to the configuration file of your application:

Note that this second technique will cause all files within a given application to be compiled in debug mode. The first technique will cause only that particular file to be compiled in debug mode.

Important: Running applications in debug mode does incur a memory/performance overhead. You should make sure that an application has debugging disabled before deploying into production scenario.

Stack Trace:

[HttpException (0x80004005): Unable to validate data.]
   System.Web.Configuration.MachineKeySection.GetDecodedData(Byte[] buf, Byte[] modifier, Int32 start, Int32 length, Int32& dataLength) +2546780
   System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.Deserialize(String inputString) +214

[ViewStateException: Invalid viewstate. 
    Client IP: 127.0.0.1
    Port: 
    User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; InfoPath.2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)
    ViewState: 9xQG6dYJ5zq2jCqMiucYRNTojwFlEGYjCH2OQX2PsmFzIZhHtD11AD5JBQmMuoIw105QqG46Ew4o8mVXLBG+T9hl2qqjTTQ/jlivQHaLBjR/cojc5VTk2aZUCmDSZBt/z1yzV8kJLFYrNmIkKAztL+eeZho/zZmCVfRAIcCyhIc=
    Referer: http://localhost:1124/Login/ApproveAppointments.aspx
    Path: /Login/ApproveAppointments.aspx]

[HttpException (0x80004005): Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that  configuration specifies the same validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster.]
   System.Web.UI.ViewStateException.ThrowError(Exception inner, String persistedState, String errorPageMessage, Boolean macValidationError) +116
   System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.Deserialize(String inputString) +251
   System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.System.Web.UI.IStateFormatter.Deserialize(String serializedState) +4
   System.Web.UI.Util.DeserializeWithAssert(IStateFormatter formatter, String serializedState) +37
   System.Web.UI.HiddenFieldPageStatePersister.Load() +220
   System.Web.UI.Page.LoadPageStateFromPersistenceMedium() +83
   System.Web.UI.Page.LoadAllState() +35
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +6953
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +154
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest() +86
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestWithNoAssert(HttpContext context) +18
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) +49
   ASP.login_approveappointments_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) +29
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +154
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +64

I tried the code that given in Source error.But could nt solve.Can anybody help?

Answer (score -1):

Ensure you have put the same machine key in the web.configs on all your machines in the cluster e.g.

```
<machineKey validationKey="AAABBBCCCDDD111222333444AAABBBCCCDDD111222333444AAABBBCCCDDD111222333444" decryptionKey="AAABBBCCCDDD111222333444" validation="SHA1"/>
```